# Can i generate Events in hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I previously worked on Ethereum which can generate "events" when a function is called or state is changed, and those events can be captured from the app by watching the state changes. 
Does Hyperledger have that functionality?
I can see "events" in hyperledger-fabric but how can I generate my own events and capture them in the node app when the state is changed?

Answer (score 4):

In Hyperledger Fabric there is a `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface` API method named:

```
// SetEvent allows the chaincode to set an event on the response to the
// proposal to be included as part of a transaction. The event will be
// available within the transaction in the committed block regardless of the
// validity of the transaction.
SetEvent(name string, payload []byte) error
```

which allows you to specify events during invocation of chaincode (aka smartcontract). Later you can register to event hub in order to get those events.

Comment: How can you catch this event then? I tried registerChaincodeEvent() method, but seems it is not working well...

Answer (score 0):

You can set an event in your chaincode such as shown in the following code:

`APIstub.SetEvent("evtsender", []byte("abcdef"))`

Then in the file that you use to perform the query you should use the `registerChaincodeEvent()`; see below the official documentation:

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/EventHub.html#registerChaincodeEvent__anchor

This could be an example:

```
let event_monitor = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let regid = null;
        let handle = setTimeout(() => {
            if (regid) {
                // might need to do the clean up this listener
                eh.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                console.log('Timeout - Failed to receive the chaincode event');
            }
            reject(new Error('Timed out waiting for chaincode event'));
        }, 20000);
        eh.connect();
        regid = eh.registerChaincodeEvent('fabcar', 'evtsender',
            (event, block_num, txnid, status) => {
                // This callback will be called when there is a chaincode event name
                // within a block that will match on the second parameter in the registration
                // from the chaincode with the ID of the first parameter.
                console.log('Successfully got a chaincode event with transid:' + txnid + ' with status:' + status);

                // might be good to store the block number to be able to resume if offline
                storeBlockNumForLater(block_num);

                // to see the event payload, the channel_event_hub must be connected(true)
                let event_payload = event.payload.toString('utf8');
                if (event_payload.indexOf('CHAINCODE') > -1) {
                    clearTimeout(handle);
                    // Chaincode event listeners are meant to run continuously
                    // Therefore the default to automatically unregister is false
                    // So in this case we want to shutdown the event listener once
                    // we see the event with the correct payload
                    event_hub.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                    console.log('Successfully received the chaincode event on block number ' + block_num);
                    resolve('RECEIVED');
                } else {
                    console.log('Successfully got chaincode event ... just not the one we are looking for on block number ' + block_num);
                }
            }, (error) => {
                clearTimeout(handle);


                   console.log('Failed to receive the chaincode event ::' + error);
                    reject(error);
                }
                // no options specified
                // startBlock will default to latest
                // endBlock will default to MAX
                // unregister will default to false
                // disconnect will default to false
            );
})
```

Anyway I am getting some problems testing it.